# Why does an error occur when creating a set from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set, callable

I have tried to execute the following basic statements in a python console and what I got is an error saying:

```
dict object is  not  callable
```

The code I executed:

```
>>> test_dict = {1:"one",2:"two"}
>>> set3= set(test_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I have gone through some questions on web but couldn't find and understand anything till now.

Comment: A dict has key-value _pairs_ ... what items do you expect to show up in your set?

Comment: You are not telling us everything. Your code does not raise an exception by itself.

Comment: @PaulBecotte By default, keys will be used whenever a dictionary is iterated.

Comment: `set(test_dict)` gives the keys, ie: `set([1, 2])`. But if above in your code you declared something like `set = {...}`, you only could be guilty for it. BTW **never** use Python standard names like list, set or dict for you own variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* construct a set from a dictionary; the set will be initialized to the set of keys in the dictionary.

However, in your case, the name `set` has been bound to a dict value, so when you write `set`, you don't get the built-in set class, but that dictionary. Write `set = __builtins__.set` to restore it in an interactive shell. In a program, search for `set =` (or `as set`) in the code before.

Comment: @avinash625 Please mention how, so that other people can benefit from your solution! If this or any other answer solved it for, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). If the problem was something else, please write your own answer (and accept it later). Thanks!

Comment: searched for the 
    set = {}
and deleted the binding that i created and then it ran fine

Answer (score 1):

You are masking the built-in `set` by assignment.

```
>>> set = {}
```

This makes the `set` name point to a new dictionary object, you can no longer use it as the built in type that creates new `set` objects:

```
>>> test_dict = {1:"one", 2:"two"}
>>> set3 = set(test_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

**Don't mask the [built-in names](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)**, simply delete the name binding you created and now everything will run fine:

```
>>> del set  # 'undos' the set={} binding 
>>> set3 = set(test_dict)
>>> set3
{1, 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has no problem run under python3 and python2 . If you got this error,it typically means you have reassign set to another object. You should check the code again.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr 13 2015, 11:43:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_dict = {1:"one",2:"two"}
>>> set3=set(test_dict)
>>> print set3
set([1, 2])
>>> set3.add(3)
>>> print set3
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> set3.pop()
1
```

and in python3 :

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_dict = {1:"one",2:"two"}
>>> set3=set(test_dict)
>>> print(set3)
{1, 2}
>>> set3.add(3)
>>> print(set3)
{1, 2, 3}
>>> set3.pop()
1
>>> print(set3)
{2, 3}
```